# what this c program will print on the screen?

Tags: c

This is my c language review question, Thanks for help

What is printed to the screen:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    float p, q=6.2;

    int t[10];

    float *x;
    int *y;  
    x=&q;

    j=3;
    i=(int)q;
    i+=5;
    j=i--;
    printf("i=%d and j=%d\n", i, j);
//_____________i=10 and j=11__________________________   

    j=15;
    i=11;
    i=j&i;
    j=i&&j;
    printf("i=%d and j=%d\n", i, j);

//_______i=11 and j=1__________________________________ 

    i=4;
    j=25;

    p=j/i*10+j%3-6;

    printf("p=%.2f\n",p);


//__________p=55.00_______________________________

   y=t;

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
       t[i]=(i==2)?2:(i*2);

   y+=2;
   printf("the value is %d\n",*y);


//____________the value is 2_____________________________   

return 0;
```

my question is what is the i=j&i and j=i&&j means in part2?

in part 3 answer is `p=55.00`, By I calculated is `(25/2)*10+1-6=57`, why i am wrong?

in part 4       what is     `t[i]=(i==2)?2:(i*2);` means?

Comment: You'll technically get the answer if you compile and run the program.

Comment: If it's an exam question you won't have a compiler handy to test.

Comment: In part 3 - it looks to me like your formula evaluates to 115. Perhaps you substituted something incorrectly. In part 4 - the calculations don't really matter (much). Look up information on the `?:` operator, also known as the `ternary conditional operator`. [This Wikipedia article might be helpful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). Best of luck.

Comment: `&` in `i=j&i` is `bitwise and` while `&&` in `j=i&&j` is `logical and`. In part 4, it is a conditional assignment. If `i` equals `2` then `t[2]` will be set to `2` otherwise `t[i]` will be set to `i*2`. `y` was initially set to the start of `t[]` therefore `y+2` is `t[2]` which will have a value of `2`.

Comment: In part 3 - `j/i` is `25/4` which is `6`. Multiply it by `10` yields `60`. `j%3` is modulo division and the remainder is `1`. So there you have it, `60 + 1 - 6` is `55`. Now print format in float with 2 decimal and you have `55.00`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I answer your first question: & is a bitwise and is used to perform multiplication bitwise by ejeplo 6 & 6 equals 110 & 110 = 110 as it operates bit by bit, && is a logical and is commonly used in conditional statements example where we need two or more conditions are met simultaneously: if a is greater than 16 and less than 30 run the following code:

```
int a = 20;
if (a> 16 && a <30) {
}
```